# Showing rollup in last line only

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, rollup

This is needed to work in both SQL Server 2005 and 2008 without having to adjust the compatibility level (if it can be done)

```
Select 
    CASE GROUPING([Store ID]) WHEN 1 THEN '[Store ID]' ELSE [Store ID] END [Store ID],
    CASE GROUPING([Cashier]) WHEN 1 THEN '[Cashier]' ELSE [Cashier] END [Cashier],
    CASE GROUPING([Register]) WHEN 1 THEN '[Register]' ELSE [Register] END [Register],
    sum([Amex]) AS [Amex],
    sum([C.Card]) AS [C.Card],
    sum([Cash]) AS [Cash],
    sum([House Acct]) AS [House Acct],
    sum([MasterCard]) AS [MasterCard],
    sum([Str Cr]) AS [Str Cr],
    sum([Visa/MC]) AS [Visa/MC] 
from 
    #a13 
group by 
    [Store ID],
    [Cashier],
    [Register] 
with rollup
```

This returns :
[image]

How could I adjust the code not to actually show the rolled up rows? Meaning remove the last 3 lines or where it has anything with [ ]. I need the `Rollup` to use in SQL 2005 so I can use the `case grouping`.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I don't know how to go about it. Can't use `GROUPING SETS(())` because it is not supported by 2005 (or needs to adjust the compatibility to 90 which I can't do, forgot the actual reason for why I can't use it). I could remove the `WITH ROLLUP` and it would work in 2008 but 2005 needs it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I understand the problem a little better, my first suggestion is to make your presentation layer a little smarter than just having to barf whatever the database sends to it.

However I'm not sure why you can't do something like this, instead of the mess you described with a temp table:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  ...your query above...
) AS x
WHERE Register <> '[Register]';
```

Comment: This worked fine. I can't do anything about the presentation layer as I am not the one in charge of it or do anything with it. I am just in charge of getting the data that is to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just put these results into temp table, removed those lines and then just select from the temp table.

Comment: This seems like a grossly inefficient solution. Since your presentation tier has to loop through all of the rows to display the data anyway, doesn't it make sense for that code to decide when to display the individual values?

Comment: This code goes to the server it all get processed there and the presentation (website) only displays my final select query. How else could I go about this within the provided code?

Comment: What does "only displays my final select query" mean? It must loop through the results in order to display them, right?

Comment: The website only sees and handles `select * from #temp` result which only has the 1 row with out the rows that have [ ] in them. All the handling and such is done on the SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

why not use a CTE instead? If you don't want all the rows produced by the rollup, return to a basic group by - but do it within a CTE, e.g.
with CTE as (
             <>
            )
select * from cte
union all
select sum(of each field) from CTE -- i.e. the grand total

you may have to introduce a constant in the CTE output (e.g. 1) and output 2 in the final row to ensure it orders properly.